# ng-src path not selecting alternative image url when the first one throws 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to display a image in my webpage when the url of that image doesn't return 404. I'm using AngularJS.

I can't check the url using ngIf because it checks whether its null or not. When the url returns 404 or not, i'll get something displayed, but if it's 404, i'll get this displayed.

[image]

Is there any way to not display the image if it returns 404 and display the image when it's there.
HTML code

```
<img class="menu" ng-if="$ctrl.companyLogo" ng-src="{{ $ctrl.companyLogo}}">
```

JavaScript code:

```
ctrl.companyLogo="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
```

Instead of displaying the default logo when the companyLogo is returning 404, its not displaying any image.

Comment: this won't work the way you expect.  it's not checking to see if the destination exists, it's checking to see if `$ctrl.companyLogo` has a value, which it does;  the 404 happens later.

Comment: @Claies Do you know anything about the my modified question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of the Image object you can check if the image path returns 404 or actual image

```
var given_src = 'http://idontexist.com/404.png';
var image = new Image();
image.src = given_src;
image.onerror = function(){console.log('doesnt exist or smth ');}
image.onload = function() {console.log('exists or smth');};
```

here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pLbdqf5d/ , also you should note that $scope.$apply in the fiddle is a hacky solution you should go with implementing a promise for this function.